# Determining what direction to face over a network with an omnidirectional camera

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, 2d, flip

I have a rather difficult problem. I am making a topdown 2D game. And I have decided to make an omnidirectional character control like realm of the mad god (Video shows at second 16 what that means). I have it all working fine and have managed to work out almost all the kinks of this sort of camera but one thing remains.

(if you dont know what effect im looking create you can see and example hee at 16 seconds mark: https://youtu.be/N2q6aXkvIiI?t=12s)

When the Camera of the the main client gets rotated more that 180 degrees Left becomes right and right becomes left and my messages to the server about flipping the given character when he is supposed to get inverted. I somewhat fixed this by making an if statement that sends an opposite flip request when your world is completely flipped.

However up and down also become a factor as they dont send requests to flip the character.

What im trying to get to is that I have overcomplicted this script I beleive when trying to get the correct messages accross all clients.

I am wondering if anyone has a logical solution to making sure all chracters on the network are always facing the correct direction at all times.

I am using socket.io and Node.js for speaking to the server.

Any input would be appeciated.

TL;DR

How would you go about making realm of the mad gods camera rotation style when all clients need to know what way everyone is facing. (see video 0:16)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have somewhat fixed this problem with a bit of a rewrite of my logic and managed to make all the magic happen on the client and keep the server out of it entirely. I do not know if what I have done is super effecient as I am rather new to coding.

The logic is that I have created a circle collider2D that represents the players field of view. so things slightly outside the camera view are included. Any collision with an object tagged "otherPlayer" will add them to a list.

I then iterate through the list, if its not empty, and I determine if the object is moving away or coming towards me. (thank you to HigherScriptingAuthority for part of the code for this :: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/left-right-test-function.31420/).

once I know that, all I have to do is grab the transform of that object and flip it accordingly. Boom it now rotates the object or player correctly no matter what rotation the main client is in.

Hope this makes sense and it helps someone:

```
private float lastDist = 0;
public float dirNum;

void CheckArea()
{
    if (listOfPlayers.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach(var otherPlayer in listOfPlayers)
        {
            float distance = (transform.position - otherPlayer.transform.position).magnitude;
            if (distance < lastDist)
            {
                Vector3 heading = otherPlayer.transform.position - transform.position;
                dirNum = AngleDir(transform.forward, heading, transform.up);
                var objectDirection = AngleDir(transform.forward, heading, transform.up);

                if (objectDirection > 0)
                {
                    var nav = otherPlayer.GetComponent<Navigator>();
                    nav.Left();
                }
                if (objectDirection < 0)
                {
                    var nav = otherPlayer.GetComponent<Navigator>();
                    nav.Right();
                }

            }
            if (distance > lastDist)
            {
                Vector3 heading = otherPlayer.transform.position - transform.position;
                dirNum = AngleDir(transform.forward, heading, transform.up);
                var objectDirection = AngleDir(transform.forward, heading, transform.up);

                if (objectDirection > 0)
                {
                    var nav = otherPlayer.GetComponent<Navigator>();
                    nav.Right();
                }
                if (objectDirection < 0)
                {
                    var nav = otherPlayer.GetComponent<Navigator>();
                    nav.Left();
                }

            }
            lastDist = distance;
        }
    }
}
```